# CSS change on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to change my grayscale value from 100 to 0 of a class when i hover on another class. Following is my code

```
 <div className="width_100">

          <img src={selfie} className="points_profilepic"
               title="Upload your profile picture"/>

          <input type="file" onChange={this.onImageChange.bind(this)}
                 className="points_picture_file" accept="image/*"/>


 </div>
```

dafault greyscale value of class `points_profilepic` is `filter: grayscale(100%);`. I want to make it `filter: grayscale(0%);` when i hover on class `points_picture_file`. I have tried several ways but did not work.

my css

```
.points_profilepic{

  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);

}

.points_picture_file{

  height:110px;
  width:120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer !important;

}
```

I tried

```
.points_picture_file:hover ~.points_profilepic{

  filter: grayscale(0);

}

.points_picture_file:hover +.points_profilepic{

  filter: grayscale(0);

}
```

But above methods did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes your HTML Order, Your element is `position:absolute;` no effect your design part

```
<div className="width_100">
 <input type="file" onChange={this.onImageChange.bind(this)}
                 className="points_picture_file" accept="image/*"/>

          <img src={selfie} className="points_profilepic"
               title="Upload your profile picture"/>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.points_picture_file:hover +.points_profilepic{

  filter: grayscale(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without change the order of HTML you must use JS to target `previous-sibling`:

```js
function func() {
document.getElementById("points_profilepic").style.filter="grayscale(0)";
}
function func2() {
document.getElementById("points_profilepic").style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
}
```

```css
.points_profilepic{

  height: 110px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  filter: grayscale(100%);

}

.points_picture_file{

  height:110px;
  width:120px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer !important;

}
.points_picture_file:hover ~ .points_profilepic{

  filter: grayscale(0);

}
```

```html
 <div className="width_100">

          <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/579/579268.svg" class="points_profilepic"
               title="Upload your profile picture" id="points_profilepic"/>

          <input type="file" onChange={this.onImageChange.bind(this)}
                 class="points_picture_file" accept="image/*" onmouseover="func()" onmouseleave="func2()"/>


 </div>
```